# Where should I ask a question relating to differences between riding static and non static cycles?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/15555) on Bicycles, but then thought maybe it's more 'sport' related.  I just don't know.

> Question: Is there a reason why one's calfs would ache on a Turbo or Spinner, but not when riding on the road?
>
> I'm not on my own on this one as at least two other people in my Spinning class suffer the same: when Spinning or on the Turbo Trainer, I can feel pressure on my calf muscles after a bit of time (usually less than 45 minutes). But I can ride on the road for up to 3 hours without feeling any pressure.
>
> I think it's something to do with leg angles: on the road, the bike changes angle slightly to best match the angle of the leg, but on a spinner or Turbo, it's fixed and so can't move.
>
> Are there any proven reasons why calfs would ache on a static bike but not on the road?

Comment: Well, what kind of differences? Health impacts, cost...?

Comment: Health, I suppose.  Primarily about muscle strain on one as opposed to the other.  I tagged it 'health' on Bicycles, which seemed logical at the time (and in retrospect, kind of adds weight to my decision to ask it on Bicycles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems as it is exercise and fitness related (muscle development and so on, [Fitness.SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) (beta) might be the right place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Wait and see what response it gets on bicycles. If the community the feels it is not on topic, they may move it to fitness anyway, but to be honest, they are already coming up with some good information.